# how to achieve a cross fade between different cameras / scenes in three.js?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

Is it possible, and if so, what is the best way to achieve the following effect in three.js:

I am displaying scene S1 as viewed from camera C1and from there:

1. crossfade to scene S2 as viewed from camera C2, or
2. crossfade to scene S1 as seen from camera C3

Any assistance helping me think about this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have these scenes actually created and are currently able to simple switch between them rather than crossfading?

Comment: alas, an abrupt switch is not what I am looking for, the intended effect is a graceful blended transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is pretty easy:

- Use 2 rendertargets to draw the different scenes from the different cameras
- Use both rendertargets with this blend shader https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/ShaderExtras.js#L1099

Comment: Thanks! I am relatively new to three.js and any sample (pseudo)code describing your answer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is there an update for this fiddle. It only displays black screen.