# Cross fade between different cameras / scenes

Tags: three.js

This is an older question "[how to achieve a cross fade between different cameras / scenes in three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118056/how-to-achieve-a-cross-fade-between-different-cameras-scenes-in-three-js)" which has a fiddle associated with it **jsfiddle.net/DW9q4/43/** which doesn't seem to work any more. It displays a black screen.

Any ideas why?

r.58

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary change is how uniforms are defined.

```
tDiffuse1: {
    type: "t",
    value: rtTexture1
},
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DW9q4/85/

three.js r.58

Comment: Is there a way to scale first texture as it fades out without scaling second texture?